# writing function in rails app for outputting info of variable, file managed by global debug value

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, debugging, zend-framework, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I used to have a php zend app that had a function like this (if I remember correctly):

```
function dxa($var, $msg){
  echo "msg:" . $msg . "<br />";
  if(GLOBAL_DEBUG){
    Zend_Debug::dump($var);
  }
}
```

Basically, this would just output variables in either model, view, or controller. It was handy for debugging. We always put it on its own line and before deploy, would run a sed script to remove any line that had 'dxa(' in it. Basically, you could turn on and off viewing the variables via the GLOBAL_DEBUG variable without resorting to xdebug or something. This could also be managed via a GET param. Is there a way to do something like this in RoR? I was thinking the view could be:

View:

```
<%=d(@location) %>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def d var
  debug(var.to_yaml)
end
```

Would like to have access in model and controller and the formatting of this is off. Any other ideas?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that functionality with the [Rails Logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger).

Comment: I currently have a custom logger. I'd ideally just like to output to the browser across anywhere in the app.